# problem with moving files with extensions with shutil

Tags: python

I have the following code that should move files from one directory to another, the problem is when I run the code it just creates the folder and not moving any file to it. can anyone help me with that?

```
import os
import glob
import shutil

def remove_ext(list_of_pathnames):

return [os.path.splitext(filename)[0] for filename in list_of_pathnames]

 path = os.getcwd()
 os.chdir("D:\\TomProject\\Images\\")   
 os.mkdir("image_with_xml")     # create a new folder
 newpath = os.path.join("D:\\TomProject\\Images\\" ,"image_with_xml") # 
 made it os 
 independent... 

 list_of_jpegs = glob.glob(path+"\\*.jpeg")
 list_of_xmls = glob.glob(path+"\\*.xml")

 jpegs_without_extension = remove_ext(list_of_jpegs)
 xmls_without_extension = remove_ext(list_of_xmls)

 for filename in jpegs_without_extension:
  if filename in xmls_without_extension:

 shutil.move(filename + '.jpg', newpath) # move image to new path.
 shutil.move(filename + '.xml', newpath)
```

Comment: Indentation is meaningful in Python.  Are you sure you copied and pasted this code correctly?  It almost looks like every line of code is in the remove_ext function and therefore nothing will run.  Add some print statements so you can understand which parts of the code are running and what they are doing.

Comment: Also, you're doing a bunch of needless work by first removing the extensions and then adding them back.  Try to simplify the code to the simplest possible thing that should work but doesn't: that is called a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

You first use ".jpeg" as extension but then when you move mistakenly use ".jpg".